# Azure Data Factory Overwrite Existing Folder/Partitions in ADLS Gen2

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-data-factory

I have my settings in my ADF Sink to Clear the folder but Partitioned via an ID

[image]

[image]
But this sink already has other partitions in that exists that I do not want to remove.

If an ID comes in, I just want to clear that specific folder/partition but it is actually clearing the full folder versus just partition.  Am I missing a setting?

Comment: Can you please confirm why you want to clear the specific folder/partition? Is the existing partition same column as the one you are configuring in sink (CorrelationId)

Comment: @SaideepArikontham I’m appending data to specific ids and want to overwrite the files that are existing as I use the same source and sink.   If I don’t remove them it would be duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite only the partitions that appear in new data and keep the rest of the old partition data, you can make use of the `pre commands` present in the settings tab of the dataflow sink. Look at the following demonstration.

- The following is my initial data which I have partitioned based on id.

[image]

- Now let's say the following is the new data that you are going to write. Here, according to the requirement, you want to overwrite the partitions that are present and keep the rest as it is.

[image]

- First, we need to get the distinct key column values (`id` in my case). Then use them in the pre commands of sink settings to remove files only from these partitions.
- Take the above data (the 2nd image data) as `dataflow1` source. Apply `derived column` transformation to add a new column with constant value say `'xxx'` (to group based on this column and apply collect() aggregate function).

[image]

- Group by this new column and use the aggregate as `distinct(collect(id))`.

[image]

- Now for sink, choose as `Cache`, check `write to activity output`. When you run this dataflow in the pipeline, the debug output would be:

[image]

- Send this array value to a parameter created in another dataflow where you make necessary changes and overwrite partitions. Give the following dynamic content

```
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value[0].val
```

[image]

- Now in this second dataflow, the source is the same data used in first dataflow. For sink, instead of selecting `clear the folder` option, scroll down where you can find `pre/post commands` sections where you give the following dynamic content:

```
concat('rm /output/id=',toString($parts),'/*')
```

[image]

- Now when you run this pipeline, it successfully executes and runs the overwrites only the required partitions, whereas keeps the other partitions.

The following is a sample partition data (id=2) to show that the data is overwritten (only one part file with required data will be available).

[image]

Comment: Thank you @saideep!  It will take me a bit to try to implement this and I will return for  additional questions/comments. - What do you think this perf would be if you have about 100K ids to apply the pre cmds to?

Comment: Hey @enavuio, I cannot say speak for its performance as it I have not tested it for large number of id's but considering the whole operation is being carried out using dataflows only, it should be good enough to achieve the requirement.

Comment: Thanks Saideep - getting invalid cmd 
Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sink1': Command concat('rm /providererroroutputcopy/CorrelationId=',toString($part),'/*') is not a valid command syntax but seeing the data just fine and also keys look just fine like yours. 

"output": {
            "sink1": {
                "value": [
                    {
                        "val": [
                            "xyz",
                            "abc",...
Wanted give you updated but will need to debug more.

Comment: Can you share the error message? The format to use rm to remove files inside all those partitions, is different for integers (as in my solution) and for strings (all id in square brackets will be removed whereas it is flower bracket for strings).

Comment: thank you for that detail as my data has IDs or all fields in strings - I had to change it.  Unfortunately - the error message is just the same - I also tried to remove the toString() but not working. 
Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sink1': Command concat('rm /output/id=',$part,'/*') is not a valid command syntax

Comment: As far as the flower - do you mean that we cannot store a string in an array and use the "rm" cmd?  That we have to store it in flower/object - {} ?

Comment: I got the [error](https://i.imgur.com/P660fEq.png) when I used the command directly in the text box is in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/BrNLkdM.png). Please open the [dynamic expression builder](https://i.imgur.com/RDydJE7.png) for pre command and then use the command `concat('rm /output/id=',$part,'/*')`. When the partitions are strings the syntax of the command would be `rm /output/id={"abc","xyz"}/*`. (for integer partitions `rm /output/id=[1,2]/*` would work).

Comment: Before passing the parts array value from pipeline, I converted it to string and replaced the `[` with `{` and `]` with `}` in a set variable activity (in a string variable) using this dynamic content `@replace(replace(string(activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value[0].id),'[','{'),']','}')`. I passed this variable to parts parameter(string) in dataflow . Then I used the command `concat('rm /output/id=',$part,'/*')` (concatenating the above string to rm command in dynamic expression builder). Check if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you specify the filename and write it to 1 single file.

Comment: You should use the comment section to get more specific information. Answering should be used only to provide an answer to the question.